# How can i make GNAT generate program listing?

Tags: gcc, ada

Make it look like tasm-generated listing)

Answer (score 3):

Call 'gnatmake' with '-S' as one of the arguments:

```
$ cat hello_world.adb
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Hello_World is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Hello world!");
end Hello_World;
$ gnatmake -S hello_world
[...]
$ head hello_world.s
        .file       "hello_world.adb"
        .section    .rodata
.LC1:
        .ascii      "Hello world!"
        .align 4
.LC0:
        .long       1
        .long       12
        .text
        .globl      _ada_hello_world
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gnatmake.html),

> Any uppercase or multi-character
>   switch that is not a gnatmake switch
>   is passed to gcc (e.g. -O, -gnato,
>   etc.)

, so you would probably do it the exact same way you'd do it with gcc.

I don't know the exact format you refer to, but [-gnatl](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gcc.html) looks interesting.